# "Partition failed with error: Couldn't unmount drive"

Tags: partition

I am trying to create a new partition so I can install Windows through Boot Camp. I boot into recovery mode using my Recovery Assistant USB and no matter what I do, when I try to resize my drive and create a new partition, I get this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using Disk Utility to verify the disk. Based on a bit of Googling, it sounds like this error can be caused by a some corruption in the boot record.

Comment: Can you add the output from the following terminal commands to your question? `diskutil list disk0` (prints the partition table as OSX sees it) `sudo gpt -r show disk0` (prints the actual GUID partition table) `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` (prints the MBR partition table, used by Boot Camp) - when Disk Utility can't partition, it's often because the GPT and MBR don't agree for whatever reason, and you have to manually fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried repartitioning with Boot Camp (just go through the Boot Camp process normally)? You shouldn't have to repartition manually in the first place.

Comment: When I go into Bootcamp I get this error:

"The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition. The startup disk must be formatted as a single Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volume or already partitioned by Boot Camp Assistant for installing Windows."

Answer (score -1):

Use Boot commands for mac os x

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a sentence. It's okay to mention an idea, but please excerpt it in the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide more details on the specific command you have in mind?

Answer (score -2):

You should install OS X on an external hard drive and wipe your internal hard drive. Hopefully, if there's nothing on the internal drive, the OS won't bother mounting it.

Comment: I've had cases where I get this error even when I run the system from an external drive.  Recent versions of OS X seem to mount the internal drive at boot whether it  needs it or not.

Comment: I would not listen to advice to wipe my disk that has the word "hopefully" in it.